# How to extract body of asterisk-indented JavaDoc block in source-code?

Tags: java, regex

I have a block of string that looks like this.

```
/** 
* Comment section for Asset Record config OnStatusChange
*
* Updated for HT342408  Set Assetmeters to inactive when the asset they are
* associated with is retired. This will also cause the condition monitoring
* point associated with the meter to be displayed as inactive.
*/


if (ASSET.retired_date.isnull){
  ASSET.retired_date = new Date();
}

var meterset = ASSET.ASSETMETER;
for (var x = 0; x < meterset.length; x++){
//println('*********meterset['+ x + '].assetmeterid' + meterset[x].assetmeterid);
meterset[x].active = false; 
//println('*********meterset['+ x + '].active' + meterset[x].active);
}
```

What I am trying to do is extract the javadoc style text comment at the top,  Everything between the /** and the */      So far I have been unable to figure out how to pull this off in java.   My latest attempt was to use a pattern but it doesn't appear to be matching.  Can anyone provide some assistance on how to pull this off easily?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*/\\*\\*.*\\*/");
System.out.println("checking text for pattern: " + p);
Matcher m = p.matcher(scriptContents);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found Match");
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `Pattern.compile` line twice? You're overwriting the old pattern. Your code is searching for this pattern `"\\[Text:(.*?)\\]"`

Comment: Can you guarantee that there will be no String like `"text /** whatever */ another test"` in your input code?

Comment: You may need to let . match newlines (/s)

Comment: @DenhamCoote does `.` not match newlines?

Comment: the code is buggy.even you have declared pattern p twice

Comment: @Cruncher depends on the engine.  Take a look at http://www.regexr.com/ - it has switches for things like that. (It also uses 'regular' regex, none of this \\'ing :))

Comment: The extra pattern compile was from a commented out bit of code that I missed when I cut and pasted the code over here.

Answer (score 1):

`String.split("/*")` will split the string into 2 Strings, so grab the 2nd String, and then `String.split("*/")` and grab the first String, which should be your text.

edit - hmm asterisks dont appear in my comment

Comment: The op wants the doc style comment. I think you need `/**` for the first split

Comment: Also, I think java splits on regex. I think you need to escape the `*`. Something like `String.split("/\\*\\*")[1].split("\\*/)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*\\*.*?\\*/",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This regex uses `DOTALL` flag to let `.` match also line separators so now `.*` can match also multi line substrings.
Also you would need to look for minimal possible match between `/**` and `*/` so instead of `.*` you need to use `.*?` (it is called [reluctant quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)). This way you will be able to find minimal matches

```
text /** fist doc */ whatever /** fist doc */ text
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of maximal ones (which are default way regex quantifies works)

```
text /** fist doc */ whatever /** fist doc */ text
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Just be careful, because regex will not recognise if matched text comes from real doc, or from some

- string literal `"text /** whatever */ another test"`
- or comment `// text /** whatever */ another test`

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/eEOmxu)

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, this worked perfectly.   :)     Although I may have a peak at the answer aliteralmind provided.

Comment: ***WARNING: Clicking the DEMO link may take you to a page which has advertisements with NSFW content***

Comment: @Krumia It is first time I hear about this kind of problem with ideone.com. Can you tell us something more about what kind of advertisements you got because if it is very strange for me (I've never seen any NSFW content there).

Comment: Not much, it was an advertisement with a bikini clad lady. But that can be NSFW depending on your workplace.

Comment: @Krumia OK, this really is NSFW in most workplaces. It is strange that site like this, which is used mainly by IT employees (most probably from work) uses such advertisement. It's at lest unprofessional :/

Answer (score 0):

This searches through the input string, line-by-line, extracting the body from each JavaDoc block (there are two in this example code), and uses a regex to eliminate the optional asterisk at the start of each line. Note that this assumes that body text is not on the same lines as open and close marks--that is, `/*` and `*/` are on lines by themselves.

Class top:

```
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
   <P>{@code java ExtractJavaDocBody}</P>
 **/
public class ExtractJavaDocBody  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
```

Establish demo input:

```
      String sLS = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
      StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder().
         append("...                     ").append(sLS).
         append("/").append("**          ").append(sLS).
         append("* Comment section for Asset Record config OnStatusChange").append(sLS).
         append("*                       ").append(sLS).
         append("* Updated for HT342408  Set Assetmeters to inactive when the asset they are").append(sLS).
         append("* associated with is retired. This will also cause the condition monitoring").append(sLS).
         append("* point associated with the meter to be displayed as inactive.").append(sLS).
         append("*").append("/            ").append(sLS).
         append("...                      ").append(sLS).
         append("/").append("**           ").append(sLS).
         append("* Another block line 1   ").append(sLS).
         append("*                        ").append(sLS).
         append("* Another block line 2   ").append(sLS).
         append("* Another block line 3   ").append(sLS).
         append("* Another block line 4   ").append(sLS).
         append("*").append("/            ").append(sLS).
         append("...                      ").append(sLS);
      String[] lines = input.toString().split(sLS);
```

Main logic:

```
      //"": To reuse matcher
      Matcher mtchrPostAstrsk = Pattern.compile("^\\*?[ \t]*(.*)$").matcher("");

      boolean isBlockStarted = false;
      for(String line : lines)  {
         line = line.trim();
         if(!isBlockStarted)  {
            if(line.startsWith("/" + "*"))  {
               //Assumes body starts on next line
               isBlockStarted = true;
            }
            continue;
         }  else if(line.endsWith("*" + "/"))  {
            isBlockStarted = false;
         }  else  {
            //Block is started
            mtchrPostAstrsk.reset(line).matches(); //Actually does the match

            //Trim to eliminate spaces between asterisk and text
            System.out.println(mtchrPostAstrsk.group(1).trim());
         }

      }

   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java ExtractJavaDocBody
Comment section for Asset Record config OnStatusChange

Updated for HT342408  Set Assetmeters to inactive when the asset they are
associated with is retired. This will also cause the condition monitoring
point associated with the meter to be displayed as inactive.
Another block line 1

Another block line 2
Another block line 3
Another block line 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a substring of a block of text, use `substring`:

```
    String commentText = "/** * Comment section for ... as inactive. */";
    int startIndex = commentText.indexOf("/**") + "/**".length();
    int endIndex = commentText.lastIndexOf("*/");
    String commentSubstring = commentText.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    System.out.println(commentSubstring); //  * Comment section for ... as inactive.
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Consider the string "/**docstring*/ somelinesofcode; /*this line of code does something!*/" The entire string will be included.

Answer (score 0):

This is from C/C++ style comments.
Globally search, will come back in capture group 1.
So, if length capture group 1 > 0, found `/** comments **/` style.

```
    # (?:(/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/)|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^/"'\\]*)
    # "(?:(/\\*[^*]*\\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\\*+)*/)|//(?:[^\\\\]|\\\\\\n?)*?\\n)|(?:\"(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^\"\\\\])*\"|'(?:\\\\[\\S\\s]|[^'\\\\])*'|[\\S\\s][^/\"'\\\\]*)"     

    (?:                           # Comments 

         (                             # (1 start)
              /\*                           # Start /* .. */ comment
              [^*]* \*+
              (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
              /                             # End /* .. */ comment
         )                             # (1 end)
      |  
         //                            # Start // comment
         (?: [^\\] | \\ \n? )*?        # Possible line-continuation
         \n                            # End // comment
    )
 |  
    (?:                           # Non - comments 
         "
         (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*     # Double quoted text
         "
      |  '
         (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*     # Single quoted text
         ' 
      |  [\S\s]                        # Any other char
         [^/"'\\]*                     # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                       # or line continuation (escape + newline)
    )
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;
$str = <DATA>;

while ($str =~ /(?:(\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/)|\/\/(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|(?:"(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^\/"'\\]*)/g)
{
      if (length ($1) > 0)
      { print "'$1'\n";}
}

__DATA__

/** 
* Comment section for Asset Record config OnStatusChange
*
* Updated for HT342408  Set Assetmeters to inactive when the asset they are
* associated with is retired. This will also cause the condition monitoring
* point associated with the meter to be displayed as inactive.
*/


if (ASSET.retired_date.isnull){
  ASSET.retired_date = new Date();
}

var meterset = ASSET.ASSETMETER;
for (var x = 0; x < meterset.length; x++){
//println('*********meterset['+ x + '].assetmeterid' + meterset[x].assetmeterid);
meterset[x].active = false; 
//println('*********meterset['+ x + '].active' + meterset[x].active);
}
```

Output >>

```
'/**
* Comment section for Asset Record config OnStatusChange
*
* Updated for HT342408  Set Assetmeters to inactive when the asset they are
* associated with is retired. This will also cause the condition monitoring
* point associated with the meter to be displayed as inactive.
*/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a class called [`FilteredLineIterator`](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/xbnjava/documentation/javadoc/com/github/xbn/linefilter/FilteredLineIterator.html) that can do as you wish.

`FilteredLineIterator` filters another string iterator (which is normally the lines in a text file), keeping or discarding each line based on the entities in which it exists: "blocks", "single line" and "stealth block" entities. Each kept line may be altered.

(`FilteredLineIterator` is part of [XBN-Java](http://xbnjava.aliteralmind.com). Download the necessary jars [here](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/xbnjava/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description).)

The below example demonstrates a `FilteredLineIterator` where all lines are kept, but only the line in the JavaDoc block (specifically, in its "mid" lines) are altered. The alteration is a regular expression replacement, which eliminates any leading asterisk--which is roughly the behavior of `javadoc.exe`

(I've added an additional "normal" [non-JavaDoc] multi-line comment block to the beginning of your input, because it's likely there's at least one normal block in a real source file. Since both "normal" and JavaDoc comment blocks both end with "*/", this demonstrates how to prevent the end line in a "normal" multi-line comment from generating an incorrect "end line found before block opened" error. This is done with a ["stealth block"](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/xbnjava/documentation/javadoc/com/github/xbn/linefilter/entity/StealthBlockEntity.html) whose only purpose is to prevent false positives such as this.)

```
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.FilteredLineIterator;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.KeepUnmatched;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.Returns;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.alter.NewTextLineAltererFor;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.alter.TextLineAlterer;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.BlockEntity;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.EntityRequired;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.KeepMatched;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.NewBlockEntityFor;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.NewStealthBlockEntityFor;
   import  com.github.xbn.linefilter.entity.StealthBlockEntity;
   import  com.github.xbn.regexutil.ReplacedInEachInput;
   import  com.github.xbn.testdev.GetFromCommandLineAtIndex;
   import  com.github.xbn.util.IncludeJavaDoc;
   import  java.util.Iterator;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
   <P>{@code java StripOptionalAsterisksFromJDLineStarts C:\java_code\example_input\JavaSnippetWithJDBlockAsterisksEachLine_input.txt}</P>
 **/
public class StripOptionalAsterisksFromJDLineStarts  {
   public static final void main(String[] cmd_lineParams)  {
      //Example setup:
         Iterator<String> itr = GetFromCommandLineAtIndex.fileLineIterator(
            cmd_lineParams, 0,
            null);   //debugPath
```

Example proper:

```
      StealthBlockEntity javaMlcBlock = NewStealthBlockEntityFor.javaComment(
         "comment", IncludeJavaDoc.NO,
         null,       //dbgStart
         null,       //dbgEnd
         KeepMatched.YES, EntityRequired.YES, null,
         null);      //dbgLineNums

      TextLineAlterer stripAsterisks = NewTextLineAltererFor.replacement(
         Pattern.compile("[ \t]*\\*(.*)"), "$1",
         ReplacedInEachInput.FIRST,
         null,       //debug
         null);

      BlockEntity javaDocBlock = NewBlockEntityFor.javaDocComment_Cfg(
         "doccomment",
         null,       //dbgStart
         null,       //dbgEnd
         EntityRequired.YES, null,
         null).      //dbgLineNums
         midAlter(stripAsterisks).
         keepAll().build();

      FilteredLineIterator filteredItr = new FilteredLineIterator(
         itr, Returns.KEPT, KeepUnmatched.YES,
         null, null,    //dbgEveryLine and its line-range
         javaMlcBlock, javaDocBlock);

      while(filteredItr.hasNext())  {
         System.out.println(filteredItr.next());
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
/*
   A non-JavaDoc multi-line comment to emphasize the need for stealth-blocks
*/
/**
 Comment section for Asset Record config OnStatusChange

 Updated for HT342408  Set Assetmeters to inactive when the asset they are
 associated with is retired. This will also cause the condition monitoring
 point associated with the meter to be displayed as inactive.
*/


if (ASSET.retired_date.isnull){
  ASSET.retired_date = new Date();
}

var meterset = ASSET.ASSETMETER;
for (var x = 0; x < meterset.length; x++){
//println('*********meterset['+ x + '].assetmeterid' + meterset[x].assetmeterid);
meterset[x].active = false;
//println('*********meterset['+ x + '].active' + meterset[x].active);
}
```