# can we get author name,method purpose using java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

can we get author name & method purpose using java reflection. I tried googling and unable to find out.

```
/**
     * purpose list of commands 
     * @return {@link List}
     * @author David
     * 
 */
public static List<String> getCommands(){
    Set<Class<?>> allClasses = null;
    List<String> commandList = new ArrayList<String>();
       return null;
}
```

from this methods, I want author name and purpose of the method. How do i get using reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaDoc comments are not part of the code, so they cannot be accessed with reflection.

If you want to extract the data from these comments, you'll need to parse the source files, in a similar way to what Javadoc Tool does when it generates API documentation in HTML format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as the @Eran's answer.

If your class is compiled, the comments are removed also!

**See also:**

- [How to extract JavaDoc comments from the source files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13024881/1834700)